# Invalid ssl certificate issue with heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku

I executed following command

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 999 -nodes -out myapp.key -keyout myapp.pem
```

And then I tried following command

```
heroku ssl:add myapp.pem  myapp.key --app myapp
```

I am getting following error message

```
!   Pem is invalid / Key is invalid
```

I am using MacBook Pro.

I already paid $20 to heroku and am using "Hostname Based Custom SSL".

Answer (score 0):

You haven't generated an SSL certificate, only a certificate signing request (CSR).  If you really want to use a self-signed certificate, you'll need to add the `-x509` option to your `openssl req` command, or sign the CSR you've already generated with a separate `openssl x509` call.